# How to troubleshoot node.js app not working on 1 of 2 identical virtual machines?

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-7, virtual-machine

I'm in process of updating an app working on a VM Windows 7 32bit and I've encountered an error.
After moving the app onto the clients VM node doesn't run it for the life of me.
The Windows versions are identical on my VM I've worked on and on the clients VM.

After nmp install and nmp run dev the app starts on my VM but on the clients one I get error that nodemon cant be found, so I install nodemon, after that I get an error that node:events can't be found - so I install events however this still does not help and I am stuck with this error:

I've reinstalled node clean multiplet times, deleted npm, tried over and over.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6ZFO.png)

edit:
by trial and error I've arrived at a weird message. I've installed node 13.14.0 on the system and while trying to npm install package-lock.json command prompt gave me this:

```
    npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for node-win-x86@21.2.0: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x86"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  x86
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: ia32
```

It's as if the Windows 7 version even tho it is a 32bit version doesnt pass the version check since it's tagged as ia32 instead of x86?

EDIT:

RESOLVED
Managed to fix it.
Removed node from package, was met with syntax errors from msnodesqlv8 and tedious. These turned out to be due to their versions being higher than node 13.14.0 supports. With a little help of chatgpt I've fixed these to fit 13.14.0 and it did the trick.

Comment: Which node version are you using? Is it the same on both machines?

Comment: Hi. I am using node.js 13.14 on both.